# Пожалуйста помогите разобраться с epoll

Tags: сервер, unix, http-server, epoll

К сожалению, прочитав несколько статей и посмотрев несколько примеров использования epoll, я так и не смог понять, какие преимущества он нам дает.

Попробую смоделировать ситуацию, у нас есть простейший http сервер, который может обрабатывать запросы только на статический контент(html, jpg и тд). Сервер имеет простейшую архитектуру - крутится в бесконечном цикле, когда ему приходит запрос на соединение, он открывает доп поток, и обрабатывает пришедший запрос в нем, в то время, как основной поток продолжает слушать порт.

Я не понимаю, как работу этого сервера может ускорить epoll. Как я понял, при использовании epoll, каждый клиентский дескриптор нужно добавлять в список потоков epoll, и когда этот дескриптор будет готов к вводу/выводу, при вызове epoll_wait нам вернется этот дескриптор, который, в свою очередь, мы сможем обработать и закрыть. Но как этот шаг поможет, если когда нам приходит http запрос и мы открываем клиентский дескриптор, он уже готов к вводу выводу.

Разъясните эти моменты пожалуйста, если возможно приведите пример архитектуры epoll сервера.
я прочел эти статьи

https://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/epoll_example.txt.html

https://habr.com/ru/post/416669/

https://habr.com/ru/company/infopulse/blog/415259/

Comment: В принципе то же, что и poll/select, но быстрее. epoll возвращает все дескрипторы,  с которым что-нибудь случилось рядом в массиве, а для poll/select надо перебирать элементы массива и смотреть, произошло ли что-то с этим дескриптором. / Самый простой варант сервера, один процесс (fork после accept) на одно соединение у вас уже стабильно работает? (про потоки (threads) пока забудьте)

Comment: @avp, да, стабильно, так в epoll же нет смысла, если не разделять обработку на потоки. Хотя щас я понял. А какие проблемы могут быть с thred?

Comment: С threads одна проблема -- алгоритм безопасного совметного их доступа к ресурсам (в широком смысле). По простому, обычно ошибок в таких программах бывает много.